# Python's imp.reload() function is not working?

Tags: python, import

Here's a concise example:

x.py:

```
class x:
  var = 'from x.py'
```

y.py:

```
class x:
  var = 'from y.py'
```

test.py

```
import imp
def write_module(filename):
  fp = open('z.py', 'w')
  fp.write(open(filename).read())
  fp.close()

write_module('x.py')
import z
print(z.x.var) # Prints 'from x.py'
write_module('y.py')
imp.reload(z)
print(z.x.var) # Prints 'from x.py'
```

I'm not sure why both print statements are the same.  How can I make python use the new definition of class x after reload()?

Comment: You could also remove the `.pyc` file, which will force Python to recompile the module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because the file creation dates (of `z.py` and its compiled counterpart `z.pyc`) are identical, so Python thinks that the file is unchanged and doesn't recompile it.

Actually, when I was trying and re-trying your code, it once worked as expected - probably because the two files happened to be created on either side of the system clock's second-changeover.

```
import imp
import time
def write_module(filename):
  fp = open('z.py', 'w')
  fp.write(open(filename).read())
  fp.close()

write_module('x.py')
import z
print(z.x.var) # Prints 'from x.py'
time.sleep(1)  # Wait one second
write_module('y.py')
imp.reload(z)
print(z.x.var) # Prints 'from y.py'
```

shows the expected result.

Comment: Another way round this which avoids having to sleep for a second is to remove the cached file. Replace your `time.sleep(1)` with `os.remove(getattr(z, '__cached__', 'z.pyc'))` (and `import os` at the top) and you get a faster version that still works.