# Module reload doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, file, python-module

I have a problem understanding why `reload()` doesn't work properly in the code below:

```
# Create initial file content
f = open('some_file.py', 'w')
f.write('message = "First"\n')
f.close()

import some_file
print(some_file.message)        # First

# Modify file content
f = open('some_file.py', 'w')
f.write('message = "Second"\n')
f.close()

import some_file
print(some_file.message)        # First (it's fine)
reload(some_file)
print(some_file.message)        # First (not Second, as expected)
```

If I change the file `some_file.py` manually with an external editor (while the program is running) then everything works as expected. So I guess it may have something to do with syncing.

Environment: Linux, Python 2.7.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I could not reproduce this with `importlib.reload` on Python 3.4 on Windows. I get the output `First ; First ; Second`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Works fine on Python 3.X indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code changes the file immediately, so the file appears unmodified.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8123038/6805304)

I've tried your code with the same 1 second sleep between file writes and it works fine

```
import time

# Create initial file content
f = open('some_file.py', 'w')
f.write('message = "First"\n')
f.close()

import some_file
print(some_file.message)        # First

time.sleep(1)                   # Wait here

# Modify file content
f = open('some_file.py', 'w')
f.write('message = "Second"\n')
f.close()

import some_file
print(some_file.message)        # First 
reload(some_file)
print(some_file.message)        # Second, as expected
```

**Workarounds**

1. Remove the `.pyc` file generated for your module (`some_file.pyc`, or something like that). That will force python to re-compile it.
2. Just change the module on the fly along with writing to a file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22952682/6805304). Something like

   ```
   some_file.message = "Second\n"
   f = open('some_file.py', 'w')
   f.write('message = "Second"\n')
   f.close()
   ```

Comment: I already tried the idea. Most of the time it works (First, First, Second), sometimes it doesn't (Second, Second, Second - when you instantly run the script for the second time). In my opinion, it's not the best idea to fill the code with sleeps, so I'm looking for a more robust solution.

Comment: I agree that it's a bad practice to pollute code with meaningless sleeps. I've meant this as an explanation rather than a solution. I've updated the answer with some workarounds.